# Is non-linear acceleration a necessary condition for an object to generate gravitational waves?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, acceleration, gravitational-waves

I was assuming every object that interferes with the gravitational field creates gravitational waves, and someone pointed out that only objects under acceleration do so. I searched through many sites and it seems that most sources support the latter idea. But what's the difference between the effect that an object has already had on the gravitational field and the effect when it's accelerating?

To my understanding, gravitational detectors like the Virgo interferometer are essentially precise instruments to measure geodesic deviation, which means if you put a calibrated Virgo beside a small Schwarzschild black hole, it will detect something(**edit**:because the black hole has caused geodesic deviation, which Virgo measures to detect waves). And, of course, if you put a Virgo beside a binary black hole system, it also does.

The thing is if Virgo can't tell the difference between these 2 types of data at any given time(not period), are these data essentially different? Moreover, even if a constant distribution can't be seen as waves, you can always use a Fourier transform to force it into waves, as long as the constant state is a combination of waves. I didn't see anything that can separate one of the 2 situations from the other. Where did I get wrong?

**Edit**:I suppose this question is more or less similar to "is an electric field an electromagnetic field?", I hope to find some details about whether these 2 questions are similar or not.

**Edit 2**:Consider a static charge, you recorded its electric field, and it's not emitting EM waves. Now the charge starts moving and you can observe EM wave emissions, but you need to filter out the waves from the electric field you've previously recorded because the electromagnetic tensors of the electric field and the EM waves are addable, in other words, they are essentially the same. Is this the case for gravitational waves as I mentioned above?

Comment: A schwartzschild black hole does not create gravitational waves as it is a spherically symmetric and mathematically a constant solution to the Einstein field equations. The page on gravitational waves on Wikipedia lists how a source could produce GW. Most sources are not going to be spherically symmetric.

Comment: [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/726151/180269) might be helpful for you.

Comment: "you put a calibrated Virgo beside a small Schwarzschild black hole..." On what basis do you make this claim (it isn't true")?